# Nginx множество 301 редиректов в один редирект

Tags: nginx, debian, redirect

Всем привет! Не нашел на просторах интернета решения моей проблемы, пишу сюда.

Есть задача написать редирект, пример:
http://site.ru//pAgE////index
должен редиректить на
http://site.ru/page

Есть ряд location'ов в конфиге nginx, а именно:

```
location ~ ^\/(.*?)\/index\.html$ {
    rewrite ^(.*/)index.html http://$host$1 permanent;
}
location ~ ^\/(.*?)\/index$ {
    rewrite ^(.*/)index http://$host$1 permanent;
}
location ~ [A-Z] {
    if ($uri != $uri_lowercase) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://$host$uri_lowercase permanent;
    }
}
location ~ /$ {
    rewrite (.+)/$ $1 permanent;
}
location ~ ^(.*)//(.*)$ {
    rewrite (.*)//+(.*) $1/$2 permanent;
}
```

СЕОшник просит чтобы все эти правила срабатывали как один редирект, у меня же возникает множество редиректов. Каким образом объединить правила в один?

Comment: Написать эти правила на нормальном языке программирования. Хотя бы на встроенном Lua  или nginScript.

Answer (score 0):

Директива `rewrite` без флага `permanent` не будет сразу же возвращать пользователю постоянное перенаправление с кодом 301, вместо этого будет происходить внутреннее изменение URI.

Источник: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite